# Using Javascript for conditional options select field

Tags: javascript, forms, conditional-statements

This problem is bugging me, but I can not find a good solution here or on almighty Google...

I'm trying to make a form with a select field with "conditional options" depending on the answers of the previous question. Below my code.

First the question which influences the next conditional question (answer is a number).

```
<div class="formblock">
<label class="screen-reader-text">Total sales</label>
<input type="number" name="sales" id="sales" value="">
<?php if($salesError != '') { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $salesError;?></span> 
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Next the Javascript to test the answer and show the options of the next question.

```
    <script>

    jQuery(function($) {
    $('#sales').bind('change', function (e) { 
    //if( $('#sales').val() == "") {
    // $('#150, #250, #500, #750, #1000, #1500').hide();
    //}
     if( $('#sales').val() > '150' ) {
    $('#150').show();
    }
     if( $('#sales').val() > '250'  ) {
    $('#250').show();
    }
     if( $('#sales').val() > '500'  ) {
    $('#500').show();
    }
     if( $('#sales').val() > '750'  ) {
    $('#750').show();
    }
     if( $('#sales').val() > '1000'  ) {
    $('#1000').show();
    }
     if( $('#sales').val() > '1500'  ) {
    $('#1500').show();
    }
    if( $('#sales').val() == '0'  ) {
    $('#150, #250, #500, #750, #1000, #1500').hide();
    }
    else{
    $('#150, #250, #500, #750, #1000, #1500').hide();
    } }); 
}); 
</script>
```

And the code from the next question with the select options. So some options only show if a minimum amount is enetered in the previous question. At least, that's what I'm trying to get done...

```
 <div class="formblock-conditional">
<label class="screen-reader-text">Present</label>
<select class="select" name"present" id="present" >
<option value="" class="txt requiredField" selected="selected">No present</option>
<option id="150" value="" class="txt requiredField" >Present 1</option>
<option id="250" value="" class="txt requiredField" >Present 2</option>
<option id="500" value="3" >Present 3</option>
<option id="750" value="4" >Present 4</option>
<option id="1000" value="5" >Present 5</option>
<option id="1500" value="6" >Present 6</option>
</select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues. I have streamlined it a bit

```js
var presents = {"Present 1":150,"Present ABC":250,"Gutschein 1":500,"Gutschein 2":750,"Gutschein 3":1000,"Gutschein 4":1500}
$(function() {
  $('#sales').on('keyup', function(e) {
    $("#present").get(0).length=1;
    var sale = this.value;
    $.each(presents,function(key,val) {
      if (sale >= val) {
        $("#present").append('<option value="'+val+'">'+key+'('+val+')</option>');
      }  
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formblock">
  <label class="screen-reader-text">Total sales</label>
  <input type="number" name="sales" id="sales" value="">
</div>

<div class="formblock-conditional">
  <label class="screen-reader-text">Present</label>
  <select class="select" name "present" id="present" class="requiredField">
    <option value="" selected="selected">No present</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. Although it is not quite what I'm looking for (yet). Instead of exact numbers it should work with "between 150 - 250" for instance. And the option in the select box should not be those numbers but a text like "present 2" etc. Sorry, tried your code but don't see how to adapt it to get these results.

Comment: I changed to use Present1/2/3... Now you get Present 1 if you have 150 or more, but less than 250. Present 1 and Present 2 if you have 250 or more but less than 500

Comment: OK, I see what you're doing. Adding 1 automatically. But what if it doesn't add up, but the options are totally different? Present 1, Present ABC, Gutschein etc.? Thanks again @mplungjan.